# Empty Delimiters Represents What

Tags: c#

```
   public class B : A { }
```

What does this { } signify. Class B inherits from class A but what does this { } do ?
I read some where that it can inherit only the protected.

Comment: it's an empty class implementation? Doesn't seem very useful in general, but certainly allowed.

Comment: Every class declaration requires { brackets }.  If you don't put anything inside of them then you are writing useless code.  No point in using B when A is identical.

Comment: @HansPassant, Brokenglass, not always useless. The whole Exception hierarchy comes close to this pattern, except for the (mandatory but without added value) constructors.

Comment: @Henk - exception hierarchies are considered un-useful these days.  Microsoft no longer recommends deriving from ApplicationException for example.

Answer (score 2):

It is a short notation for

```
class B : A
{
   // no members
}
```

meaning that B is a derived class but does not add any members (properties, methods, ...). The `{}` are mandatory for a class definition, members are not.

Taken literally, this pattern could be useful for making different types (subsets) but in general this would be demo code, used to explain something and not to be used in production.

Answer (score 2):

The first curly brace begins the area where the contents of the class can be defined and the second ends that area. You can't omit the braces even if you aren't going to add anything.

Have a read of [the MSDN docs on classes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx)